# How in asyncio run independence co-routine in other co-routine from run loop.Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

Necessary , with the main loop run coroutine that something will be done. And from it ,start another coroutine, which will not block. Use Python 3.5

```
import asyncio,time  
async def cor1():
    for i in range(10):
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        print("cor1",i)

async def cor2():
    for i in range(10):
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        time.sleep(1)
        print("cor2",i)

async def main():
    asyncio.ensure_future(cor1())
    asyncio.ensure_future(cor2())
    print("cor3")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
asyncio.ensure_future(main())
loop.run_forever()
```

Now the main loop creates two coroutines.But they do not run parallel,one after another. Until someone one complete, the other will not start its work.Of course you can run them on different threads and to establish communication using queues. But is it possible to do this with the help of asyncio in python 3.5

Answer (score 1):

This decision helped me

```
import asyncio,time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
def cor1():
    for i in range(10):
        print("cor1", i)
        time.sleep(2)

def cor2():
    for i in range(10):
        print("cor2", i)
        time.sleep(1)

executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(2)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

asyncio.ensure_future(loop.run_in_executor(executor, cor1))
asyncio.ensure_future(loop.run_in_executor(executor, cor2))

loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: does this run in parallel? i mean different processes. if not how I can do this ?@онстантин  елопокатуновичь

Answer (score 0):

this is a way how you can run them in parallel:

```
import asyncio

async def cor1():
    for i in range(10):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("cor1", i)

async def cor2():
    for i in range(10):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("cor2", i)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
cors = asyncio.wait([cor1(), cor2()])
loop.run_until_complete(cors)
```

note that `time.sleep(1)` (unlike `asyncio.sleep(1)`) is a blocking call and will not run concurrently.

Luciano Ramalho's book *Fluent Python* has an excellent chapter about coroutines and `asyncio`... just in case.

Comment: Thank you. although I did not see a special difference. The time.sleep(1) , I mean the execution of a long-term operation.In your example, when one function has not finished its action, the other begins to have not effect.And my goal is to achieve parallel execution

Comment: if you need parallel execution of blocking tasks you either need [threads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html?highlight=threading#module-threading) or [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#module-multiprocessing). asyncio is something like 'cooperative multitasking'; all your tasks need to be coroutines and yield cpu time.